# Выполнение нескольких команд на удалённой машине

Tags: ssh, shell

Возникает часто задача: подключаться на конкретный сервер по SSH, после подключения выполнить там всегда одну и ту же последовательность из трёх комманд, а вот уже потом могут быть какие-то разные действия.

Хочу автоматизировать первую часть процесса.

Удалось написать bash скрипт, который при запуске открывает отдельное окно терминала, выполняет подключение по SSH и оставляет окно терминала открытым:

```
#! /bin/bash
xfce4-terminal -e 'ssh username@host'
```

Вот как бы мне ещё в этом сеансе ssh-подключения выполнить ещё три заранее заданные команды? Я слабо понимаю синтаксис bash-скриптов. Пробовал просто дописать эти команды вот так:

```
#! /bin/bash
xfce4-terminal -e '
ssh username@host
комманда_1
комманда_2
комманда_3
'
```

И как минимум строчка с ssh выполняется. Я это понимаю по тому, что в окне терминала запрашивается passphrase для ssh-ключа, и если ввести неправильно, то он спрашивает ещё два раза - в точности, как и при нормальном ssh-подключении.

Но при вводе правильной passphrase окно терминала просто тут же закрывается.

Comment: комманда_1 && комманда_2 && комманда_3

Comment: @SeniorAutomator а куда это нужно писать? На одной строчке с ssh-подключением? Внутри тех же одинарных кавычек? Попробовал пару вариантов, у меня что-то не то получается. Мне нужно, чтобы после выполнения этих трёх комманд ssh-подключение оставалось открытым и я мог бы с ним продолжать работу уже вручную.

Comment: вот пример `ssh username@host 'ls -l; ps -aux; whoami'  ` поставь знак ; между командами и возьми в  кавычки

Comment: *чтобы после выполнения этих трёх комманд ssh-подключение оставалось открытым и я мог бы с ним продолжать работу уже вручную* — это уже **совершенно** другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

список команд, передаваемых программе *ssh*, надо заключить в кавычки:

```
#!/bin/bash
xfce4-terminal -e 'ssh username@host "команда1; команда2; команда3"'
```

чтобы после выполнения всех команд программа *ssh* не завершалась:

- до нажатия <kbd>enter</kbd>, последней командой можно указать, например, `read`
- некоторое время, последней командой можно указать `sleep 10` (пауза в десять секунд)

---

в [шебанге](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)) не должно быть пробелов!