# Как удержать терминал и сессию ssh открытой после выполнения команды?

Tags: python, ssh

Запускаю приложение test.py, которое должно подключить меня к удаленному серверу и перебросить в папку web там же и при этом оставить терминал открытым мне для работы:

```
subprocess.call("xfce4-terminal --execute ssh user@x.x.x.x -p 1234 cd /home/web", shell=True)
```

А оно просто выполняет команду cd на сервере и сразу закрывает терминал. Как исправить?

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо,заработало! $SHELL выручила. Напишите как ответ, а я отмечу правильным

Comment: Спасибо!Получилось с $SHELL! напишите как ответ, а я отмечу правильным

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/914366/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/627675/178576)

Answer (score 1):

попробуй через Popen.
Call просто вызывает программу дожидается окончания и возвращает код возврата.

```
cmd = "cmd /K ping ya.ru /n 10"
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False)
```

Comment: Не работает. Мне нужно открыть xfce терминал на убунту

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.call("xfce4-terminal --execute ssh user@x.x.x.x -p 1234 -t 'cd /home/web && $SHELL'", shell=True)
```